# Typescript - using a nested interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface that looks like

```
export interface Foo {
  data?: Foo;
  bar?: boolean;
}
```

In some cases, the data is being used as `foo.data.bar` and in other cases `foo.bar`. When I use the interface above I'm seeing:

`Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Foo | undefined'`

This feels kind of weird, but how can I adjust this so that `data` could have Foo's types?

Comment: The problem here is that `data` can be `undefined`, so you have to check before access it

Answer (score 3):

The question mark indicates that `data` could be either an instance of `Foo`, or it could be `undefined`:

```
data?: Foo;
```

The error you're seeing is due to this - if `data` is `undefined`, there's no `bar` property to access.

If `data` will *always* be populated with an instance of `Foo`, you can remove the `?`, which will resolve this issue:

```
data: Foo;
```

Alternatively, you can use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) when accessing `bar`:

```
const bar = foo.data?.bar;
```

Or, you could check if `foo.data` is defined:

```
if (foo.data) {
   const bar = foo.data.bar;
}
```

Comment: "The question mark indicates that data could be either an instance of Foo..."

It indicates that a property is **optional** and is either defined or, like you said, undefined. An *instance* of `Foo` would look like `let foo = new Foo()` where `foo` is the instance. `foo.data` can still be undefined.